# How to select multiple files with mouse in Visual Studio Code explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Windows Explorer, I can select several objects in a folder by drawing a rectangle with the mouse over them. Can I select several objects in VS Code Explorer in the same way? Maybe you need to enable this option in config or download an extension for this purpose? I already know I can do that with Shift and Ctrl keys.

Comment: If you can already do it with Shift and Ctrl why do you need another method

Comment: @rioV8 I like to draw rectangles with my mouse.